# Input textbox value is not showing when using minDate and maxDate in jQuery datepicker

Tags: php, jquery, datepicker

I am using jquery ui datepicker. After adding minDate and maxDate, values in input box not showing. Input box values are fetching from database using mysql and php. If I didn't set minDate and maxDate I can see values in input box. Please help me to solve this issue.

**html**

```
<input type="text" name="summerSeasonYear" id="summerSeasonYear" value="15.10.18">
```

**Script**

```
$('#earliest_summer_close').datepicker({
        dateFormat: "dd.mm.yy"
 });

var summerYear = $("#summerSeasonYear").val();
var start      = new Date("May 01, "+summerYear);
var end        = new Date("October 31, "+summerYear);
$('#earliest_summer_close').datepicker('option', 'minDate', start);
$('#earliest_summer_close').datepicker('option', 'maxDate', end);
```